# equal? and record-type

Tags: scheme, r6rs

Suppose I have the following Scheme (R6RS) code:

```
(define-record-type typeA
 (fields
  (mutable A)))
```

and that I create two records:

```
(define X (make-typeA 123))
(define Y (make-typeA 123))
```

I can't understand why `(equal? X Y)` and `(equal? (make-typeA 123) (make-typeA 123))` return `#f`.

I read the R6RS standard ([section 11.5](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.5)) but I didn't really understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_436):

> The equal? predicate treats pairs and vectors as nodes with outgoing edges, uses string=? to compare strings, uses bytevector=? to compare bytevectors (see library chapter on “Bytevectors”), and uses eqv? to compare other nodes.

In other words, your use of `equal?` is really just doing the same thing as `eqv?` since that's how it's specified for records (see last line of above).

Chapter 6.1 has this to say about `eqv?` of records:

> If obj1 and obj2 are both records of the same record type, and are the results of two separate calls to record constructors, then eqv? returns #f.

In your code, the two records are the results of two separate calls to the constructor. Hence they cannot be `eqv?`.

Some dialects of Scheme may allow you to use structural equality on records. For example, in [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org) you can declare a record as `#:transparent` to get structural equality. I'm not sure you can get this behavior in standard Scheme.

Comment: It is hard to understand why `equal?` works for lists by comparing all elements of the lists and works for vectors by comparing all elements of the vectors but does not work for recods by comparing all fields of the records. Smells like a language design bug.

Comment: @ceving It's the correct language decision because, without any further assumptions, record fields should be treated as opaque. Conceptually, a record is more than just a vector of its fields. The general record is not `#:transparent`, so to speak.

Comment: @Marc Why should a record be more than a vector with named field? And what exactly is this "being more"? BTW: SRFI-9 defines records as vectors.

Comment: @ceving The *implementation* of SRFI 9 uses vectors, but this does not mean that records are *conceptually* vectors.  In any case, the R6RS record facility is much more powerful than SRFI 9; by using protocols and modularization through libraries, individual fields of a record become an implementation detail of the library defining this record type. If `equal?` were allowed to peek into arbitrary records, an abstraction barrier would be breached.

Comment: @Marc Can you give an example for code that would break, if an `equal?` for records would exist? Gambit for example has it: `(define-type point x y) (equal? (make-point 1 2) (make-point 1 2)) ; => #t`. In which way is code for Gambit limited by having an `equal?` comparing the fields?

Comment: Of course, R6RS code that assumes otherwise would break if record comparison would suddenly no longer use `eqv?` but a field-wise comparison. So let us take for a moment that R6RS had left `equal?` on records unspecified. Then Gambit's semantics would not break anything directly, but it would expose implementation details, countering encapsulation. Only if you view a record just as mere a vector with named fields (and a type tag) it would not be the wrong thing, but R6RS's records are more than mere vectors.

Comment: @Marc Once again: can you give an example where this "R6RS's records are more"-thing is beneficial? Which library relies on it and what is the advantage in that particular case?

Comment: @ceving This is nothing particular about R6RS. Whenever you want to separate abstract data types from their implementation (and want to make reasoning about your program not too hard), not exposing implementation details is beneficial - in any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with R6RS, but a quick google search suggests that

the key thing here is [mutability](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-7.html#node_sec_6.1):

> If obj1 and obj2 are both records of the same record type, and are the
>   results of two separate calls to record constructors, then eqv?
>   returns #f.

Comment: Well, at first thank you for your answer, I agree that `eqv?` returns FALSE, since it is TRUE only if the object are the same object. E.g. `(eqv? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))` returns FALSE, but `(equal? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))` returns TRUE, becouse they have the same "shape"

Comment: I have also tried to define a new record-type `typeB`, that is the copy of `typeA` except that is field is `immutable` but, `(equal? (make-typeB 123) (make-typeB 123))` continues to be FALSE.